# How to detect who is the Xth "liker"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Just wondering before I start looking through all the documentations. Is there an easy way to see who is the Xth "liker" ?

Thanks

Comment: Refresh the page every second and check who is the Xth :)

Comment: Lol.. that could do the trick but I would like a better solution. :P I woud like to find a way to reward the Xth user to encourage others to spread the words.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the users who liked a post (link, image, etc) using the [FQL *like* table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/), but there's nothing about the ordering of the results you get, you can check (or assume) if they are ordered by time.

I think that the best option would be to register to the [*edge.create* event](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) using the javascript sdk and then when someone likes the object in question you send an ajax request to the server, check the count and return an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a special event to match the like-action? I can't see it

Comment: As I wrote, the "edge.create": fired when the user likes something (fb:like)